# Google Chrome and jabber connection

Tags: linux, google-chrome, security, debian, jabber

I just see in netstat output that Google Chrome established jabber connection to Google IPs. Anybody have ideas why? GMail chat is off.

```
root@debian:~# netstat -tnp
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State          PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 xxx:52130    173.194.69.125:5222     ESTABLISHED 11386/chrome    
tcp        0      0 xxx:52128    173.194.69.125:5222     TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx:50504    69.59.197.29:80         ESTABLISHED 11386/chrome
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the same thing. Google searches appear to indicate that it has something to do with chrome sync. Apparently that is the protocol google uses for sync.